# Structuring a Qt Database Program

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a Qt program in c++ that will be the front-end for a MySQL database. I have worked through the examples and feel I understand the basics, but still have a couple of questions regarding how to structure a Qt database program.

1. Where do you put the database connection? The examples have the database connection in main. It seems like the connection should be in a separate class.
2. Can anyone recommend a fairly small example of a working program that I could study?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-sql.html

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I have been working through those examples. Are those examples typical of how you would write a production program?

Comment: it all depends on requirements. Try to come up with real production program requirements and try to understand if all of them can be achieved by code in samples. Qt samples are pretty good.

Comment: I am writing a app to track some information at my job. Right now I am planning on tracking tools (check-in/check-out) and vehicle maintenance. But it is mostly for me to learn more about Qt programming.